# Does a website have to save an image in order to get text from it?

Tags: java, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to build a website, on which the user needs to upload an image with text on it. Now the website is suposed to get this text from the image.
My question is do I need to save the image in order to get this text?
If yes where should I save it?
The reason for asking this question is that I was able to display the image on the website without saving it but not getting the text.

Comment: Sure, you can keep it in memory. But memory is limited, so depending on the traffic you get you may fill it up rather quickly.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Is the image automatically in memory?

Comment: It depends on how you handle it. Do you have some code that does this ? We might tell you of we see it.

Comment: If by "save" you mean store on permanent storage (hard drive etc), then your answer is no. You'll likely be loading the image into memory (as said above) and extracting the text from there. For any more explanation you'll need to tell us how your system will work, e.g. is it client side (so the user's PC extracts the text with JavaScript) or server side (so the image is sent across the internet and the server extracts the text)?

Comment: From the way you ask this, it seems you don't quite grasp how a web site works. Basically when a user uploads an image, the server gets a stream handle, and can either load that stream to memory or save it to the server's disk. Do you understand what the client side and what the server side is?

Comment: @dantechguy I am sorry by save I meant store.

Comment: And @RealSkeptic I am sorry you are right I am still a beginner and trying to learn. So I don't actually know on which side to extract the text. Any suggestions maybe?

Comment: That actually depends on what you want your website to be. Do you want to be able to control how users can use your service? Do you want to enforce tracking of your users using the service? Or even keep some images? If any of these are yes to you and you don't care about overhead, then do it in your backend. Do you care if your source is visible to people? Do you care if people can use it offline? If no then do it in your frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to execute a triggered process once the user loads the image, you could use some OCR mechanism in order to extract the text, avoiding the image storage.

For example, the [Tika project](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-app) allows the extraction of text from images/documents by just running the .jar:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.25.jar -t uploadedImage.png
```

Seems like a live project, as its last version ([1.25](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-app/1.25/tika-app-1.25.jar)) was deployed one month ago. It uses [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) to perform the OCR processing, so you should also have that installed on your host(s).

It supports image recognition since version 1.17

> Apache Tika 1.17 has been released! This release includes new support
> for automatic image captioning

More info about the Tika Project in its [homepage](https://tika.apache.org/) and also in its [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.tika/tika-core/latest/index.html).

---

In order to avoid a synchronous behaviour, you could also store the images in some type of queue or just your usual database, and process them later; This would allow you  to perform the operation asynchronously and also to store the images just for a limited amount of time, until the OCR mechanism is applied on them.

Once processed, you could also compress the images and persist them in order to have some kind of back-up of the original content (just in case something fails).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the OCR mechanism will work just fine.